# Currency library for Java

Tags: java, currency

Is there some currency converter library that enables to convert a value from a specific currency to another? Or should I implement my how class for this?

If someone has some kind of example it would be great...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally you should not write your own formulas to convert the currency due to the dynamic nature of currencies. It will be a good idea to access some public APIs, which can be reliably used to do the currency conversion. One of such API is [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html) currency convertor API. Yahoo API is very simple. The basic general request for getting the current currency rate between two currencies looks like:

> http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=[From Currency][To
>   Currency]=X&f=l1&e=.cs

For example, in order to get the current currency rate between US Dollars and Israeli Shekels, the following request should be constructed:

> http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDILS=X&f=l1&e=.cs

Getting the currency rate information is pretty straight forward. It starts with a basic interface to define a general converter behavior:

```
public interface CurrencyConverter {
    public float convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws Exception;
}
```

And the implementing class with a basic main application showing its usage:

```
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class YahooCurrencyConverter implements CurrencyConverter
{
    public float getConversionRate(String from, String to) throws IOException
    {
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = builder.build())
        {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + from + to + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);

            return Float.parseFloat(responseBody);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException
    {
        YahooCurrencyConverter yahooCurrencyConverter = new YahooCurrencyConverter();
        float current = yahooCurrencyConverter.getConversionRate("USD", "ILS");
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT: Yahoo or any other provider is not obliged to provide such APIs unless you are not paying them. So you may need to look for some paid APIs in case you are building a commercial applications depending on them. Or you need to be vigil to be sure that free APIs are UP and RUNNING properly for you**

Comment: IMO, an API maintained by something as big as Yahoo is far better than every static library you could ever find. +1.

Comment: @amp Added a word of caution in the resolution. Please read that as well.

Comment: I will check that too :) Have you some suggestion about paid APIs?

Answer (score 3):

May you could take a look at the [Currency Converter](https://code.google.com/p/currency-converter-api/) library.

> Currency Converter is a Java library which provides API for currency
>   conversion. It uses different bank web-services to fetch rates and
>   provides a single programming interface for any of supported
>   web-services.
>
> Currently these web-services are supported:
>
> - bank-ua.com
> - GoogleFinance web-service is under development for now

Example taken :

```
// create an instance where USD is a default currency to convert from, and EUR a default one to convert to
// Using one of the implementation: BankUaCom
CurrencyConverter currencyConverter = new BankUaCom(Currency.USD, Currency.EUR);

// convert USD to EUR (the first parameter is amount of money you'd like to convert)
currencyConverter.convertCurrency(1f);

// the same
currencyConverter.convertCurrency(1f, Currency.EUR);

// the same
currencyConverter.convertCurrency(1f, Currency.USD, Currency.EUR);

// convert EUR to USD
currencyConverter.convertCurrency(1f, Currency.EUR, Currency.USD);

// and you can continue with any other supported currencies...
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert it online or entering specific values previously?
Maybe this will help: http://www.panticz.de/Simple-Java-currency-converter